# how to make new variables looping through two variables in dataframe

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I want to know how can I make new variables by looping two variables in dataframe.

I am trying to mutate a dataframe by using two variables.I made a code using mutate function and it works fine with just few columns.

```
df
n     sd2_t    sd1_t     sd2neg_t     sd1neg_t
1     20       22        10           11
2     25       26        20           22
3     30       33        15           12

df2<-df%>%
dplyr::mutate(sd2_s=sd2_t*n,
              sd1_s=sd1_t*n,
              sd2neg_s=sd2neg_t*n,
              sd1neg_s=sd1neg_t*n)

Expected output
n sd2_t sd1_t sd2neg_t sd1neg_t sd2_s sd1_s sd2neg_s sd1neg_s
1    20    22       10       11    20    22       10       11
2    25    26       20       22    50    52       40       44
3    30    33       15       12    90    99       45       36
```

But I have more columns to mutate and I want to make the code more simple.I tried looking up "for loops" and `lapply` function but could not solve the problem by myself and need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is just a vectorised operation over each row, there's no need to explicitly loop.
Just multiply the whole chunk of your dataset, and then assign to new columns with a slight renaming:

```
dat[sub("_t$", "_s", names(dat[-1]))] <- dat[-1] * dat$n
dat
#  n sd2_t sd1_t sd2neg_t sd1neg_t sd2_s sd1_s sd2neg_s sd1neg_s
#1 1    20    22       10       11    20    22       10       11
#2 2    25    26       20       22    50    52       40       44
#3 3    30    33       15       12    90    99       45       36
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="n     sd2_t    sd1_t     sd2neg_t     sd1neg_t
1     20       22        10           11
2     25       26        20           22
3     30       33        15           12", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` , we can use `mutate_at` select columns which end with `"t"` and multiply each one of them with `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("t")), list(s = ~. * n))

#  n sd2_t sd1_t sd2neg_t sd1neg_t sd2_t_s sd1_t_s sd2neg_t_s sd1neg_t_s
#1 1    20    22       10       11      20      22         10         11
#2 2    25    26       20       22      50      52         40         44
#3 3    30    33       15       12      90      99         45         36
```

---

Not that it's needed since you already have a vectorised solution from @thelatemail but since you were trying with `lapply` one way to do it would be

```
df[sub("_t$", "_s", names(df[-1]))] <- lapply(df[-1], `*`, df$n)
```

Comment: What does `list(s = ~. * n)` do? This also adds `_s` at the end rather than replacing `_t`.

Comment: @thelatemail `list()` is the new way to apply function to each column (previously it was `funs()`) and by specifying `s = ` we create a new column. If we don't add a name `df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("t")), list(~. * n))` would just replace existing columns. Regarding column name, I am not sure how we can control it within `mutate_at` but adding another line of `rename` or `rename_at` should do it.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thank you very much for your answer !   I wanted to change [*n]part to [sqrt(sd2_t*(1-sd2_t)/n)]and recieved an error message"non-numeric argument to binary operator". Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Tamura Would you like to do it for all the columns or just `sd2_t` column ? Also looking at the formula the (`1 - sd2_t`) part would give you a negative number and taking `sqrt` of that would return `NaN`.

Comment: @Ronak Shah I want it for all the columns. Thanks for pointing out about the negative number. This function is for the different dataframe which all the number is less than 1. My question was not accurate.

Comment: @Tamura okay..In that case we can do `df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("t")), list(s = ~sqrt(. * (1 - .)/n)))` In `vars` we need to select columns where we want to apply this formula so here in this example it will select all columns which end with "t".

Comment: @RonakShah Your answer solved the problem. Thank you so much !